# SQL Server syntax error for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting a syntax error trying to create a stored procedure, although the exact same code runs perfectly as a query. I can't see the error myself, so any help would be appreciated.

The error is:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DataSelect, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'OrderedYTD'.

And the code is simply:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DataSelect
(
@TargetPdc int
)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Refresh Data Here
    EXEC DataUpdate

    -- Select Data for Report
    WITH OrderedYTD AS
    (
        SELECT custextract.*, histextract.*,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY custextract.custcustno ORDER BY histextract.salesytd desc) AS RowNumber
        FROM custextract 
        INNER JOIN histextract 
            ON custextract.custcustno = histextract.histcustno
        WHERE (custextract.ecall = 'Y')
    ) 

SELECT OrderedYTD.*
FROM OrderedYTD
WHERE RowNumber <= 10 and pdc = @TargetPdc;

END
```

I've run everything beginning at the WITH statement (minus the variable in the WHERE clause) as a query multiple times with no issue. Is there a syntactic difference using the CTE inside a stored procedure? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a semicolon before your `WITH`, otherwise it gets treated as a modifier to the preceding statement.  Just change this line and it should work:

```
EXEC DataUpdate;
```

If you don't terminate all your statements with semicolons, standard practice is to put them before your `CTE` definition:

```
;WITH OrderdYTD AS
```

Comment: You should explain it the other way round: Terminate the previous statement with a `;` instead of "prepending" a `;` to the CTE. https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the lesson. I'll have to start getting better with terminating my statements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Don't tell Aaron, I'll never hear the end of it :P